# Posting only part of a file with Python's poster.encode

Tags: python, multipartform-data

Using the poster.encode module, this works when I post a whole file to Solr:

```
f = open(filePath, 'rb')
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({'file': f})

# use wt=json because it's more convenient to navigate    
request = urllib2.Request(SOLR_BASE_URL + 'update/extract?extractOnly=true&extractFormat=text&indent=true&wt=json', datagen, headers)   # assumes solrPath ends in '/'
extracted = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

However, for some files I'd like to send only the first n bytes of the files. I thought this would work:

```
f = open(filePath, 'rb')    
mp = MultipartParam('file', fileobj=f, filesize=f)
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({'file': mp})

# use wt=json because it's more convenient to navigate    
request = urllib2.Request(SOLR_BASE_URL + 'update/extract?extractOnly=true&extractFormat=text&indent=true&wt=json', datagen, headers)   # assumes solrPath ends in '/'
extracted = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

...but I get a timed out request (and the odd thing is that I then have to restart apache before requests to my web2py app work again). I get a 'http 400 content missing' error from urlopen() when I leave off the filesize argument. Am I just using MultipartParam incorrectly?

(The point of all this is that I'm using Solr to extract text content and metadata from files. For video and audio files, I'd like to get away with sending just the first 100-300k or so, as presumably the relevant data's all in the file headers.)

Comment: The first arg to MultipartParam is the name, here 'file'. I'm passing the file as fileobj=f. The value= argument expects a string, and can't be used when using fileobj=.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having trouble is that mime encoding introduces sentinels in the post, if you don't specify the file size - that means that you have to do [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) so that the web server knows when to stop reading the file. But, that's the other problem - if you stop sending a MIME encoded POST to a server mid-stream, it'll just sit there waiting for the block to finish. `Chunked transfer encoding` and `mixed-multipart mime encoding` are both dead serious when it comes down to message segment sizes.

If you only want to send 100-300k of data, then only read that much, then every post you make to the server will terminate at the byte you want and the web server is expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but does this mean the web server will fall over from one bad request? Seems crazy. Was I only seeing subsequent requests fail because of something to do with session handling? Would requests from another user/browser have worked after a bad multipart request

Comment: The server won't fall over - that single connection would stall. Subsequent connections would open a new socket. Session data should be orthogonal as the session is meta to the socket connection.

Comment: So why did requests to other pages in the same web2py app hang?

Comment: Could be that it's trying to pipe-line the requests and the first partial blocks everything else, or if the web2py app isn't threaded/async? Really, it could be anything - I'd wrap the whole thing in a try/except and log the error to see the backtrace. You might also want to try tcpdumping the connection between apache and solr.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Sorry I can't accept your answer, though, as how to 'only read [100-300k]' using poster still escapes me. Any case, that issue is irrelevant now.

Comment: I slave over a hot web browser all day long and this is the thanks I get? Harumph! :D